# Can you use Azure Policy for assigning roles to users/groups in IAM?

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-policy

I've got multiple resource groups. Each resource group is tagged with *OwnerTeam:TeamName*. There's an AD security group for each owner teams and users are added to those groups.

Logic example would be as follows:

If a resource group has a tag of *OwnerTeam:DataScience*, add *TeamDataScience* security group to that resource group as a Contributor. And so on for other teams...For this, I can either create multiple if/then blocks in the policy definition or create an initiative and group these policies together for all the teams.

Question is that is it possible to do this with Azure Policy definitions?

I know it can be easily done via a PowerShell script but a policy assignment would be more convenient.

Comment: It seems that we cannot do that. Because we have no way to get the object id of security group in the policy. But when we assign role with arm template, we need to provide the object id : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.authorization/2017-10-01-preview/roleassignments.

Comment: @JimXu what if I supply the object id in the policy definition? Is it possible to assign rbac roles using policy definition?

Comment: If so, you can use `DeployIfNotExists` to run arm template to assign role.

Comment: @JimXu that makes sense. I've decided to just use powershell for this because it's going to get super complicated otherwise for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for your response!